# Smack 4.1 response with an "feature-not-implemented" error message to an custom IQ with the type 'set'

Tags: java, smack

If I send a XMPP example message with the type='result' to the application everything is fine. But if I change the the type to 'set' or 'get' the application replies with an error message "feature-not-implemented". 
This is a weird because I follow a tutorial from the producer side.

### Details:

I tried from this page http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/providers.html 
the example **Custom IQProvider example**.

I use Gradle 2.9 with the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    //xjc 'com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin:jaxb-xew-plugin:1.1'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-java7:4.1.0"
    // Optional for XMPPTCPConnection
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0"
    // Optional for XMPP-IM (RFC 6121) support (Roster, Threaded Chats, …)
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0"
    // Optional for XMPP extensions support
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.0"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

I implemented the classes MyIQProvider and MyIQ according to the description and register the provider with:

```
ProviderManager.addIQProvider("myiq", "example:iq:foo", new MyIQProvider());
```

If I send the following message **(type='set')** to the Smack Java application:

```
<iq type='set' from='apfel_vie@jabber.de/colibriVtn' to='birne_vie@jabber.de/colibriVen'>
  <myiq xmlns='example:iq:foo' token='secret'>
    <user age='42'>John Doe</user>
    <location>New York</location>
  </myiq>
</iq>
```

Then the **application replies with**:

```
<iq id='time_1' type='error' to='apfel_vie@jabber.de/colibriVtn' from='birne_vie@jabber.de/colibriVen'>
    <error type='cancel'>
        <feature-not-implemented xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
    </error>
</iq>
```

The type='get' results in the same behavior.

But if I only change the **type to 'result'**:

```
<iq type='result' from='apfel_vie@jabber.de/colibriVtn' to='birne_vie@jabber.de/colibriVen' id='time_1'>
  <myiq xmlns='example:iq:foo' token='secret'>
    <user age='42'>John Doe</user>
    <location>New York</location>
  </myiq>
</iq>
```

The Java Smack application **does not reply** such **an error message**.

What do I have to add/change that the application does not reply this error message in the case where the type is equal to set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need o register an IQ request handler: https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.7/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/XMPPConnection.html#registerIQRequestHandler-org.jivesoftware.smack.iqrequest.IQRequestHandler

Comment: Hi Brother, Im facing same issue..As you said. I did registerIQRequestHandler(new IQRequestHandler() and Override methods returns null..is it right? Still Im getting same issue. Plz give your commend

Comment: @Manikandan sorry for my late reply. I hope, you have already solved your problem. Nevertheless its hard to tell what exactly goes wrong in your case. Maybe it helps if you see a working code. Here is the link to the related code of my working project: [here](https://github.com/faustmann/colibri/blob/master/colibri-openadr/src/main/java/openADR/XMPP/XMPPChannel.java)